# Persist Callback channel in wsdualhttpbinding

Tags: .net, wcf

I have A WCF service (Duplex using `wsdualhttpbinding`) and a web application which communicates with it.

Service contains 2 or more methods when client calls a method (say `A()` ) async, the method creates an object (which may take 2 to 5 mins). The object contains a unique id. I will maintain a dictionary `<CallbackChannel, uniqueID>`.

If there are any events pertaining to any of the objects created I will have to notify corresponding client. I am getting Callback Channel based on unique id of the object.

The problem is with persisting the callback channel of the client. I would like to know in what format I can store the channel(in db). And how to recreate the channel when I need it.

I managed to create Callback channel of the web application based on the address and binding using below statement.

```
 Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
 ICallback callBkClient = ChannelFactory<ICallback>.CreateChannel(binding, new      EndpointAddress(clientAdress));


 callBkClient.Notify("Wow");
```

I am getting exception:

```
The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the


binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method


is implemented properly.
```

Comment: "How can I persist the callback channel?" You cannot. The client in WCF needs to open up a return path and notify the server of the endpoint. Persisting that information on its own serves no purpose. Consider if there is a way to use a `Sub/Pub` pattern. That should be much easier to implement. Could you explain the problem you are trying to solve? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I have client which uses WCF service to upload a package (a set of documents). This package will have an id. After uploading (a lengthy process which may take more than 10 mins), client tool receives an acknowledgement ( this is a straightforward call back). I will store packageID and the client callback instance/channels in a dictionary.

Comment: Reviewers go through this package and add their comments. For every comment they add, client tool should receive a notification - a callback again. But this time 1- if the client is down, I must be able to save the notification to database 2- If server goes down meanwhile the dictionary <packageid, channel object> will have no values stored. So I need to save client callback channel (or those values using which I can create a channel) in database.

Comment: Aron can you tell me if we can use wsdualhttpbinding in pub sub pattern. Also how to deal with persistant subscribers in that. I have gone through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx, but when I used another client application's binding (publisher which fires event) and create client (subscriber) object with address (saved in db), client methods are not called at all. It is neither throwing exception nor calling the intended client.

Comment: What does "I must be able to save the notification to database" mean? I sounds more like you want to have asynchronous reliable delivery to the client. In which case DATABASE BAD. Use a MQ framework instead.

Comment: I am writing logs to db already. Now i am maintaining a table which just saves addresses of client tools, logid and notification sending status. If the status is failed then service has to retry sending notification. No my client doesnt want to use MSMQ, cause it needs complicated settings at client side. Client tool should be a simple web app.

Comment: I said MQ, who said anything about `MSMQ`? Besides, there is nothing "simple" about what you are trying to achieve. I agree that `MSMQ` is awful, but at the end of the day you are trying to implement a (square wheel) `ESB`. I have heard good things about `RabbitMQ`. Your problem domain is called `Reliable Messaging`, its a thing in computer science, and a solved problem, big enough that entire applications are designed to solve it.

Comment: Can you please give me references to MQ. And do we need any tools other than VS for this?

Comment: http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#dotnet-dev You will need to run a RabbitMQ service on your server. But on the client side its just `AMQP` so you should be able to easily connect with just plain old libraries. You can even use a `WCF` binding to abstract it out, so you can configure it as `MSMQ` transport in future (or even `WebSphere`).

Comment: I have just seen these articles on Reliable Messaginghttp: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2013/10/26/wcf-bindings-how-to-implement-reliable-messaging.aspx http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/wcf-reliable-messaging/ Do these really help me.